# Invalid backend model specified: catalog/product_attribute_backend_startdate_specialprice error when editing products

Tags: product, error

i'm new to magento and to building a website in general. when i try to add/edit/delete a product i get this error message: 
Invalid backend model specified: catalog/product_attribute_backend_startdate_specialprice

i was succesfull before but i changed a few things, like adding a new attribute set and installing a language pack and i don't know where i went wrong. 
how do i fix this error?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT backend_model FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'special_from_date';
```

You'll get

```
catalog/product_attribute_backend_startdate_specialprice
```

Change it to

```
catalog/product_attribute_backend_startdate
```

To run in console

```
UPDATE eav_attribute SET backend_model = 'catalog/product_attribute_backend_startdate' WHERE attribute_code = 'special_from_date';
```

Comment: I got: catalog/product_attribute_backend_startdate_specialprice but how do i change it to catalog/product_attribute_backend_startdate

Comment: See updated code

Comment: It does still not work. Is this a magento bug?

Comment: I can only assume it happens during Magento upgrades. You need to find correct backend model. By the time I answered it was 'catalog/product_attribute_backend_startdate'. It can be other model by now. Or you just need to clean your cache.